# python TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, qt, plugins, pyqt4

I am working with python plugins for QGIS.I am using python2.5 and pyqt4 .My **init** method takes 4 argument.When i am trying to display form using 
window = DlgQueryBuilder()  ,m passing no arguments.My .py code is as follows:

```
class DlgQueryBuilder(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, db, iface, parent):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_Dialog.__init__(self)
        self.dialog = QtGui.QDialog(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.db = db 
        # ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DlgQueryBuilder()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\rt_sql_layer_working\DlgQueryBuilder.py", line 1176, in <module>
window = DlgQueryBuilder();
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

what exactly arguments i need to pass??

Comment: Please be careful with indentation when you post Python code. It's very important to the meaning of the code. I tried to fix it; I think this is what you meant.

Comment: ... are you serious??? It's right there in your `__init__()` for your `DlgQueryBuilder` class. Pass in what you expected to get when you wrote that class (except for `self`, Python will pass that in automatically).

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know what those arguments are supposed to be?

Comment: yes..i tried window = DlgQueryBuilder('postgres','')...m doing RnD on the same..what is mean by iface?

Comment: you could also set defaults in your `__init__` if you want to be able to pass it nothing (other than self).  with something like `def __init__(self, db=None, iface=None, parent=None):`  obviously don't use none though, use something that makes sense

Comment: okk thanx:) now its coming TypeError: 'sip.methoddescriptor' object is not callable..i dnt have sip in my project.

Comment: i changed this..def __init__(self,db=None, iface=None, parent=None):...rest all is same as above..plz help me out.

Comment: not callable means youre using something like a function when its not.  such as `x=5; x()`  so whatever line that error is coming from you must have done that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `db`, `iface` and `parent` arguments, as defined in your `__init__` method declaration.

Comment: okk thanx:) what is TypeError: 'sip.methoddescriptor' object is not callable??